# Sending sms using AWS sns outside sandbox, still need to verify the new phone number first?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-ruby

I keep looking for the informaion on AWS SNS services of SMS.
I would like to make sure the question before I request AWS account being moved out of the SMS sandbox.

I am trying to use this services on a product running on Heroku, which means I have to use the region on `US East (N. Virginia)` `us-east-1`. But the product users mainly live in Asia. I test it in sandbox mode, and it can receive the message.

Here comes the question:
**If AWS account exits SMS sandbox and try to send SMS to a new phone number, do I still need to verify the phone number first then it can receive the message?**

I read those two document, but cannot ensure the services. Really appreciate any answers to help me figure out.

- [1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-phone-number-as-subscriber.html
- [2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sms-sandbox-moving-to-production.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to verify phone numbers you wish to send SMS messages to once you have exited the SMS sandbox. This is strictly a requirement for accounts in the SMS sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it in CLI and then in you app

1. get the number of your client in app
2. put the value in this sintaxe:

   aws sns create-sms-sandbox-phone-number --phone-number
3. ask the customer for the code and put it in this syntax

   aws sns verify-sms-sandbox-phone-number --phone-number  --one-time-password
4. send it

   aws sns publish --message "Hello friend, you are subscribed!" --phone-number

IN CLI:

```
aws sns create-sms-sandbox-phone-number --phone-number <value>
aws sns verify-sms-sandbox-phone-number --phone-number <value> --one-time-password <value>
aws sns publish --message "Hello friend, you are subscribed!" --phone-number <value>
```

IN APP:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['aws','sns', 'publish', '--message', '"Hello, world!"', '--phone-number', '+5511123456789'])
```